# Get Users HeartBeat using AVAudioRecorder in iOS

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I need to get users heart beat per minute using `AVAudioRecorder` and use it in my application.

I tried using `AVAudioSession` to set my microphone gain to get the I/P but its failed to get the heart beat, is there any way to get heartbeat using my application?
 my code i have tried so far

```
 NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//here i took cache directory as saved directory you can also take   NSDocumentDirectory
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];//at this path your recorded audio will be saved

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,

                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,

                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,

                                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                                nil];

NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];
 AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
 [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
 [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
 [audioSession setInputGain:1.0 error:nil];

if( !audioRecorder ) {

    UIAlertView *alert  =
    [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning" message: [error localizedDescription] delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;

}

if ( error )
{
    NSLog( @"error: %@", [error localizedDescription] );
}
else {
    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    [self recordAudio];//Mehod to Record Audio
}
```

}

```
-(void) recordAudio
{
 if (!audioRecorder.recording)
  {
   audioRecorder.delegate = self;
  [audioRecorder recordForDuration:10];//Here i took record duration as 10 secs 

 }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague in what you are asking. Are you trying to record the user's heartbeat by having them press the iPhone against their chest or are you using some other attached device?

Comment: hi.. how you recorded users heart beat? will you please help me?

Comment: have you found anything on this ? Can you please give me some hint ?

Comment: I also want same to record the audio with phone's microphone press against chess. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Something you may want to try is using the peak meter power trick and the low pass filter code from the below tutorial. I would think your phone would chug through the updateMeter overhead to stay on pace with a heart beat. Basic logic is to turn on recorder, update meters, get max power, run filter, compare to a threshold to see when a "beat" occurred, then ref system time or use a repeating timer to run the above functions. Pressing phone mic against bare chest is probably best (w/o auxiliary hardware), imho. Good luck! Let us know if you get it work.

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/